# 'order' (bootsrap 4 grid) does not work as expected in Safari IOS

Tags: ios, css, safari, bootstrap-4

This code works perfectly in desktop on windows. but when i test it in safari ios the third col always collapse and jump to a new line.

here is the code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 order-sm-4">
      Second in sm+, last in mobile
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 order-3">
      Last in sm+, Second in mobile
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anybody else experienced it? is it a bug?
Thanks

Comment: Safari has several flexbox "bugs", but haven't specifically seen this, nor can I repro it.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: 11. tested it on my ipad

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote the order classes wrong. Bootstrap is mobile first so `col-sm` for example is `sm` and **up** (to `lg`).

This is probably what you want:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 order-3 order-sm-1">
      Second in sm+, last in mobile
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 order-2">
      Last in sm+, Second in mobile
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Tell me if there's any issue with this code!*